# The 'sub' claim value is different between Access and Id tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using the Resource Owner Password grant flow and requesting id token as well (the `scope` includes `openid`). I am sending the following to the endpoint:

- `client_id`
- `client_secret`
- `grant_type=password`
- `username`
- `password`
- `scope`

In the response I get the access token and the id token. The value for the `sub` claim is different between the two tokens. Why is this the case?

**Update**

It seems that the user id is actually an `oid` claim. This is described in [Azure AD ID token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens).

Text describing the `oid` claim:

> The immutable identifier for an object in the Microsoft identity system, in this case, a user account. This ID uniquely identifies the user across applications - two different applications signing in the same user will receive the same value in the `oid` claim. The Microsoft Graph will return this ID as the `id` property for a given user account. Because the `oid` allows multiple apps to correlate users, the `profile` scope is required in order to receive this claim. Note that if a single user exists in multiple tenants, the user will contain a different object ID in each tenant - they are considered different accounts, even though the user logs into each account with the same credentials.

Text describing the `sub` claim:

> The principal about which the token asserts information, such as the user of an app. This value is immutable and cannot be reassigned or reused. The subject is a pairwise identifier - it is unique to a particular application ID. Therefore, if a single user signs into two different apps using two different client IDs, those apps will receive two different values for the subject claim. This may or may not be desired depending on your architecture and privacy requirements.

However, I am still not clear why the `sub` claim is different between the access and id tokens.

Comment: Well, the Id token is meant for your app, i.e. the sub claim is unique for your app. And the access token is meant for some API you are calling, so the sub claim is unique within that. You can use either as an immutable identifier for the user, though you'll need the oid if you want to reference the user in e.g. MS Graph API.

Answer (score 7):

The subject (`sub`) claim is unique for the user and the service for which the token is intended (identified by the audience (`aud`) claim).

Usually, the ID Token and Access Token audiences will be different: the ID Token audience is the client app where the user is signing in, and the Access Token audience is the resource server the client app will attempt to access (on behalf of the signed-in user).

Answer (score 1):

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type is not supposed to be used for user authentication as per the OpenID specification, only flow with that interact with the user through the [authorization endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication) are allowed to do so (i.e. Implicit, Authorization Code, Hybrid and None grant type flows at the time of writing).

If you receive an ID token using the ROPC flow, then the Identity Provider proposes specific means that are out of scope of the OpenID Connect spec and may have specific and non-standard features that should be documented.

In any case, on Client side you should only rely on the `sub` claim in the ID Token. The Client is not supposed to parse the access token as it is only meant to be used by the resource server.

The `sub` claim depends on the IdP policy and the client configuration. The `sub` claim may be unique to the application (or application group). Please refer to [Subject Identifier Types](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SubjectIDTypes) section of the specification.